# APS Webhhok API : Webhook Trigger on acc index status "Finished"

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-construction-cloud, autodesk-webhooks

We are creating a APS webhook api that triggers on event "dm.version.added"( When a new version of an item (file) is added to a folder in ACC )

Once we receive webhook event and file urn, we are creating an index of file to get model properties data [ model property api ]
Then we had to recursively keep on checking if the index state is "Finished", so we could get the model property data

We want to know if there's a webhook event available, that could trigger webhook once the index status is finished.
Or if there's any alternative way we can get model property data without continuously checking for its translation to be completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not have webhooks for ACC Model Properties API to trigger when index status changed, but this is a good suggestion, I will report this back to our engineering team for their awareness.